# How to customize QTreeWidget header's font

Tags: python, pyqt

Using:

```
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
tree.setHeaderLabels(['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3'])
tree.setColumnWidth(0, 48)  
tree.setColumnWidth(1, 48)  
tree.setColumnWidth(2, 48)
```

`QTreeWidget` is created. Its column headers are given names. And headers horizontal sizes are set.

Now I would like to customize the headers font size.

```
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setPointSize(8)
tree.headerItem().setFont(0, font)
```

But `.setFont` used in syntax like this does not have any visible effect on font size used in headers.

I've also tried:

```
tree.headerItem().setFont(0, font)
tree.headerItem().setFont(1, font)
tree.headerItem().setFont(2, font)
```

with no success. What method to use to customize font size used in QTreeWidget's column headers?

## EDITED LATER:

Example 1 makes the column headers larger with no effect on font size (?!):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
tree.setHeaderLabels(['One','Two','Tree','Four','Five'])
font=QtGui.QFont()            
font.setPointSize(24)
tree.header().setFont(font)
tree.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Example 2 tries to use QSS = no effect on font size again:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
tree.setHeaderLabels(['One','Two','Tree','Four','Five'])
tree.header().setStyleSheet('font: bold 24px; font-size: 32pt; font-family: Courier;')
tree.setStyleSheet('font: bold 24px; font-size: 32pt; font-family: Courier;')
tree.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Example 3 uses setHeaderItem. No success:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()

font=QtGui.QFont() 
font.setPointSize(36)
item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
item.setText(0,'Column name')
item.setFont(0,font)
tree.setHeaderItem(item)    
tree.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EXAMPLE 5 via MAIN WINDOW:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow()
mainWidget=QtGui.QWidget()
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
mainWindow.setStyleSheet('QWidget { font: bold italic large "Times New Roman" }')
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
tree.setHeaderLabels(['One','Two','Tree','Four','Five'])
mainLayout.addWidget(tree)
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDIT # 2

I've just run these example codes on another machine (OSX). And to my surprise the code is working and the header font is set properly. Interesting what could be a reason it is working on one Mac and doesn't work on another? Could it be a `sip` issue? Qt Version? PyQt version? Here is the screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to just use QSS for this:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: Could you post an example on how to use QSS to change the header font properties?

Comment: Try QWidget { font: bold italic large "Times New Roman" } - verify if that changes the header font. If it does, then you just need to find the correct widget name. I remember there being some hunting for some of the Qt widgets because they didn't have the name you'd expect. You could also use obj.setName("some-name"); in the code and then use the QSS of #some-name { font .. } (just like CSS)

Comment: Like so:  `tree.header().setStyleSheet('QWidget { font: bold italic large "Times New Roman" }')`   ?

Comment: I'd actually set the MainWindow (since QWidget is the base of all QT widgets, it should cascade down to all widgets (including the header)). Some things can't be modified by QSS. Other things cannot be modified on the fly by QSS and instead require you to initialize the QSS against the application when it starts.. It's a great idea but because of some of the behaviors it has it can be clunky to use.. Hopefully it'll work!

Comment: This doesn't work: `tree.header().setStyleSheet('QMainWindow { font: bold italic large "Times New Roman" }')`

Comment: No no... don't set the tree's stylesheet - set the MainWindow's stylesheet and make sure it's 'QWidget { font: ..', the point of CSS (and QSS) is the *cascading* aspect. By setting a wide-scope setting like that at the tip-top of your widget tree, it cascades down to all children.

Answer (score 2):

**`QTreeWidget` column header fonts *absolutely* are adjustable.**

For those arriving here from the distant dystopian future, the sanest way to do so is by styling the `QHeaderView::section` selector in the stylesheet associated with the `QMainWindow` widget for your application. This approach sanely centralizes all styles into a single stylesheet *and* enables instant preview of those styles in Qt (Creator|Designer).

### ...wut?

Specifically, assuming Qt (Creator|Designer):

- Right-click on the `QMainWindow` widget in the *Object* tree view for your application.
- Left-click on the *Change styleSheet...* menu item.
- Copy and paste the following QSS:

  ```
  QTreeWidget QHeaderView::section {
      font-size: 8pt;
  }
  ```
- Click *OK.*

*Voilà!* Qt stylesheets (QSS) are uncannily powerful. All too often, they're the *only* means of accomplishing a given aesthetic task in a cross-platform and forward-compatible manner. <sup>...which kind of sucks, actually.</sup>

Note lastly that the `QTreeWidget` parent selector above is technically optional in this case, but permits a single tree widget rather than *all* tree widgets to be styled (e.g., `QTreeWidget#muh_widget QHeaderView::section`, styling the column headers for a single tree widget with the object name `muh_widget`).

### Tell Me More, Good Sir!

Gladly, kind gentleman. See also:

- This [relevant StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456379/2809027)
- This [relevant Qt forum post.](https://forum.qt.io/post/125570).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the font to be the same for the entire header, you should be able to do:

```
tree.header().setFont(font)
```

Comment: I tried `tree.header().setFont(font)` too. Doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, it works on my system.  What version of Qt are you using?  What operating system?

Comment: Platform: OSX. QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR: Version: 4.10.4-snapshot-315a27c0f0a7

Comment: Oh, I'm on Windows 7, so I can't really see what you are seeing.  Also, I'm sure you've tried this, but have you tried setting the point size to something really large, like 20?  On my setup, 8 looks about the same as the default size.  (Sorry if it's a dumb suggestion.  Just like to rule out all possibilities.)

Comment: I've just posted three examples. None of them works. I have reached the end of internet googling for the answer. Probably the header's font is not customizable.

Comment: I've just posted EXAMPLE 5 (in my original question). Please take a look. It doesn't work for me.... But thanks for trying!

Comment: Sorry nothing is working for you.  Here is my last guess. Try this line: `QtGui.QApplication.setDesktopSettingsAware(false)`  The documentation says you must put it before creating the QApplication object.  If it works, you may be affected by: [QTBUG-5469](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-5469). Even if this makes the font work, though, it could cause other problems with your app.

Comment: Unfortunately `QtGui.QApplication.setDesktopSettingsAware(False)` made no difference. It is time to admit `QTreeWidget`'s columnt header's font is not adjustable.

Comment: **`QTreeWidget` column header fonts *absolutely* are adjustable.** For those arriving here from the distant future, the sanest way to do so is via the ``QHeaderView::section`` stylesheet selector. See [this relevant StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456379/2809027) and [this relevant Qt forum post](https://forum.qt.io/post/125570) for implementation details.